# Contraire de "enfin"

Tags: antonyme

Je cherche un antonyme de « enfin » (dans le sens du soulagement souvent utilisé en début ou fin de phrase).

Un exemple familier: "Il vient d'arriver, merde!". Il faudrait remplacer merde par un mot du registre courant véhiculant la notion d'urgence et de finitude qu'on retrouve dans enfin mais en y ajoutant la contrariété.

Comment: « Déjà » avec la bonne intonation, voire un soupir ?

Comment: @Édouard je ne veux pas dépendre de l'intonation. « déjà » est trop ambigu.

Comment: Peut-être "forcement" ou pour éviter toute ambiguïté, "hélas" ou "malheureusement."

Comment: Et puis, « , à la fin », à la fin de la phrase avec la virgule y ajouterait un sens d’exaspération en gardant, peut-être, la notion d'urgence et de finitude .

Comment: En relisant les réponses, je me rends compte que je n’ai pas compris la question comme tout le monde. Je comprends que tu veux que le locuteur exprime son agacement à l’arrivée de quelqu’un. « J’aurais préféré qu’il arrive plus tard », sous-entendu « je ne peux pas le sentir ». Est-ce bien cela que tu cherches à exprimer ?

Comment: @Édouard La phrase compte peu, c'est un exemple, hélas est vieillot mais çass rapproche de ce que je recherche.

Comment: '(Il est arrivé) comme un cheveux sur la soupe' insiste sur le côté regrettable de l'arrivée plus que sur le délai trop court par rapport a l'attendu.

Answer (score 3):

Je ne trouve pas de solution parfaite, mais quelques idées qui me viennent:

- **Il est tout de même venu/Il est quand même venu**. L'accent ici est davantage porté sur le fait qu'on n'espérait plus que ça arrive (d'où une touche de contrariété, mais très légère).
- **Il a fini par arriver**. Dans ce cas l'accent est mis sur le temps passé avant l'arrivée de la personne.
- **Il est finalement arrivé** Similaire à l'exemple précédent.

Dans les exemples ci-dessus, il n'y a pas réèllement de notion marquée de contrariété dans la formule. Je pense que la solution la plus simple revient à l'exprimer via un mot supplémentaire placé avant ou après la phrase, des mots comme **Dommage**, **Tant pis**, **Hélas** (plus formel) ou encore comme dans l'exemple de la question des intejections comme **Mince**, **Merde**, ...

Je rejoins aussi l'avis d'Édouard: l'intonation et un éventuel soupir joue beaucoup dans cet exemple.

Une solution idéale resterait selon moi: *(soupir)* **Il est quand même venu...**

Comment: Il est vrai que hélas est trop formel mais néanmoins correspond à ma demande.

Comment: *Déjà* est défini comme contraire (antonyme) de *enfin* par Le Robert, *hélas* exprime en plus une plainte, une douleur, un regret, mais n'est pas l'antonyme de *enfin*